# CMake error define_property command is not scriptable

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build the example `factory_demo` from the Espressif [esp-box repo](https://github.com/espressif/esp-box) that I cloned from GitHub while running in a Ubuntu Linux session.
After setting up `esp-idf` work environment; from within the example project folder; issuing the command: `idf.py flash monitor` as instructed in the `README.md` CMake failed with error: `define_property command is not scriptable` while referrring to  line 1218 of cmake-3.22 module `ExternalProject.cmake`. See the attached screenshot.

The contents of the used CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
# The following lines of boilerplate have to be in your project's
# CMakeLists in this exact order for cmake to work correctly
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)

if(DEFINED ENV{RMAKER_PATH})
  set(RMAKER_PATH $ENV{RMAKER_PATH})
else()
  set(RMAKER_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../components/esp-rainmaker)
  message("-- Not find RMAKER_PATH, default is ${RMAKER_PATH}")
endif(DEFINED ENV{RMAKER_PATH})

set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS
    ../../components
    $ENV{IDF_PATH}/examples/peripherals/rmt/led_strip
    ${RMAKER_PATH}/components
    )
    
add_compile_options(-fdiagnostics-color=always)

project(factory_demo)
```

[Error and part of the file reported with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc3vU.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in esp-idf ([espidf_v40_builds_suddenly_failing](https://www.reddit.com/r/esp32/comments/hyx2fh/espidf_v40_builds_suddenly_failing/)).
I would try to remove the string `$ENV{IDF_PATH}/examples/peripherals/rmt/led_strip`